# Which backup files are needed for a successful restore?

Tags: backup, recovery, rman, oracle-xe

Considering the built-in 'Backup Database' script (backup.bat) that comes with a new installation of the Oracle Express 11g Edition, after finishing the script execution, what folders/files should be copied to an external media (`XCOPY` backup) so the database could be fully restored the database after a new install?

Environment:

```
Windows Server 2003
Database is in ARQCHIVELOG
Datafiles/Tablespaces are set-up as default (user data is being allocated in USERS Tbs)
```

I have a guess that the folder `[InstallDir]\oraclexe\app\oracle\fast_recovery_area` should contain all of what I need, but I'm afraid it isn't enough.

*PS: Question moved from ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/413762/oracle-database-11g-express-edition-built-in-backup-files-to-be-saved (too old to migrate)*

Comment: Yes, unless you specified otherwise, the fast recovery area contains everything you need - rman backup set and archive logs.

Comment: What exactly does backup.bat do?

Comment: @Roy - Thank you very much for the prompt answer. Could you please point your two comments out in an answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @Roy - Just one more doubt: Do control files and parameter file are included in the `fast_recovery_area`?

Comment: Please see my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The included `backup.bat` (windows) or `backup.sh` (all other platforms) script found under `$ORACLE_HOME/config/scripts` will do the following:

- Check that the user running the script is in the DBA or DBOPER system groups
- Check that the database is in archivelog mode and have the `FAST_RECOVERY_AREA` parameter configured.
- Back up the database to the fast recovery area under `XE/backupset` (online/warm backup using RMAN)
- Create a pfile as `$ORACLE_HOME/XE/dbs/spfile2init.ora`
- Autobackup `control file` and `SPFILE` to the fast recovery area under `XE/autobackup/`
- Switch to the next online redo log file, letting the current one be archived
- Create a log of the backup operation, in the user's home directory

The archive logs are already located in the fast recovery area under `XE/archivelog`

Note that the PFILE is created in the oracle home, but it is not required to restore the database, not even to a new server. **Everything you *do* need is located in the Fast Recovery Area.**

That's not to say that it's not a good idea to additionally back up the oracle home.